# Can't pass data to another view controller in when preparing for segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to pass an object to another view controller but I get an error when I try to set the property of the view controller object.

[image: error_xcode]

Comment: Can you add the code of another ViewController for reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty informative. It says the class `ViewController` has no public or internal property called `data`. You'll have to declare a property called `data` in class `ViewController`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var data: String?

}
```

Answer (score 2):

the class you have that is named `ViewController` needs to have a public variable named data.

Your `ViewController` class could look something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // This is your public accessible variable you can set during a seque
    var data: String?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        print(self.data)
    }

}
```

Also, your prepareForSegue function can be simplified like this

```
if let displayTodoVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController {
    displayTodoVC.data = "Hello World"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ViewController` is obviously missing a string variable named `data`.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

    var data: String? // Make sure you have this defined in your view controller.
}
```

I would also suggest that you use a conditional unwrapping of the destinationViewController in your `prepareForSegue`.

```
prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController {

        viewController.data = "Hello World"
    }
}
```

For future posts, please refrain from posting images of code. You should include code as text in your questions.

Happy coding :)

[The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)